# Stuck updating a single variable updated by multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an app that uses multiple threads to write to a single variable "theVar" below.  99% of the times I have the correct data, but at times some data goes missing.  I have been trying to solve this for almost a week now and I am really lost.  It just happens all of a sudden and I lose data, a very serious issue.  What am I doing wrong?

```
class Singleton {
    private volatile Singleton instance;
    private volatile String theVar = null;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void setVar(String newVar) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            theVar = newVar;
        }
    }

    public String getVar() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return theVar;
        }
    }

    public void appendVar(String text) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            theVar += text;
        }
    }

    protected Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        Singleton instance = this.instance;
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                instance = this.instance;
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = this.instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: `instance` is not `volatile`. Your [DCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) is broken. Further as `lock` is an instance variable and you always lock the entire instance method, what's wrong with the `synchronized` keyword?

Comment: Boris - thanks for the link, I will look at DCL.  So instead of locking the variable "theVar", I should lock the entire instance?  What about synchronized?

Comment: Thanks Boris I have fixed the singleton with DCL.  It still doesn't work, fails intermittently :(

Comment: The only issue I see is that the `getInstance()` method could actually create more than one "singleton."  Best I think just to take a lock around the whole method, rather than just the part where you create a new Singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddy, for creating Singleton my recommendation would be to use below approach which is 100% thread safe and no synchronization issue because it leverages Java's class loading mechanism.

Like this class `Provider` will be loaded only once *(JVM will never load a class twice)* when you `getInstance()` will be called first time by first thread and hence only one instance of Singleton class will exist.

Even if 2 threads will try to call `getInstance()` method at same time, but JVM will not load `Provider` two times, and since we are creating `Singleton` class instance as part of static initialization, which mean on class loading, so only one instance will exist.

In your case, probably 2 threads at very exact same time were causing some problem; give a try to this and I hope you should get 100% results. If not then please provide code of how you are running the same.

```
    public class Singleton {
        private Singleton() {
        }

        private volatile String theVar = null;

        public void setVar(String newVar) {
            synchronized (this) {
                theVar = newVar;
            }
        }

        public String getVar() {
            synchronized (this) {
                return theVar;
            }
        }

        public void appendVar(String text) {
            synchronized (this) {
                theVar += text;
            }
        }

        private static class Provider {
            static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
            return Provider.INSTANCE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this technique worked quite well.  I am getting correct results in all my runs so far.

Comment: Cool buddy, glad to know.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
  public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    private volatile String theVar = null;


    public synchronized void setVar(String newVar) {
        theVar = newVar;
    }

    public String getVar() {
        return theVar;
    }

    public synchronized void appendVar(String text) {
        theVar += text;
    }
  }
```